# ZendFramework cuts strings from first non a-z char when inserting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, utf-8, character-encoding

When I insert some data with `Zend_Form` to database with non `a-z` characters like `chrząszcz` it cuts me this string and in database I have saved only `chrz`.

Everyting in `MySql` is set as `utf8_general_ci`, when connecting with `MySql` I call `SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'`, files are also `UTF-8`.

I have no idea what to do with that.

I wrote also standalone script and it inserts and reads me that string correct. `ZendFramework` reads it also correct. The problem is only with inserting.

Do anyone know how to fix it ?

**UPDATE:**

If I insert data with:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO unit SET name = 'chrząszcz'");
```

in `ZendFramework` it works. Problem is with inserting that way:

```
$unitTable = new Model_Unit_Table();
$unit = $unitTable->createRow();
$unit->setFromArray($form->getValues());
$unit->save();
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Problem is with using `Zend_Filter_StringToLower` - it modifies string `chrząszcz` into `chrz�szcz`.
How to get this filterto work correct ?

Comment: Does $form->getValues() return the correct string?

Comment: No. `var_dump` of `$form->getValue()` gives `chrz�szcz`. When `var_dump` a `$_POST` superglobal it gives correct `chrząszcz`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responding to your comment:

> No. var_dump of $form->getValue()
>   gives chrz�szcz. When var_dump a
>   $_POST superglobal it gives correct
>   chrząszcz.

Does this work?

```
$testArray = array('name' => 'chrząszcz');

$unitTable = new Model_Unit_Table();
$unit = $unitTable->createRow();
$unit->setFromArray($testArray);
$unit->save();
```

If yes, your problem may be more Zend_Form related.

**Edit:**

Your filter needs to use [mb_strtolower()](http://www.php.net/mb_strtolower) instead of [strtolower()](http://www.php.net/strtolower).

**Edit2:**

Try this:

```
$filter = new Zend_Filter_StringToLower();
$filter->setEncoding('UTF-8');
```

Comment: Yes. I discovered problem - look at `UPDATE 2` please.

Comment: Is it possible to set encoding to `UTF-8` permanently for all filters in all forms ?

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't know any builtin method to do this. But you could extend the `Zend_Filter_StringToLower` with your own filter which uses UTF-8 as default encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is an encoding problem. Strings dropping off at the point of the first non-standard (i.e. above the ASCII character set) character is most often caused by inserting UTF-8 data in a non-UTF8 context so my first suspicion would be that the encoding of the database connection is not properly set.

- Can you try `$db->query("SET NAMES utf8");` before calling the insertion commands?
- Is the connection Zend_form uses definitely `$db`?
- Are you 100% sure the page your form is in is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: 1. `SET NAMES utf8` changed nothing. 2. How to check/do it ? 3. Yes, I am 100% sure.

Comment: 2. I'm not a Zend man so I don't know, sorry. But I imagine the classes have a `$db` object? --- Can you post a live example of this?